# INSERT INTO runs only 1 time?

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","bird") ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bird");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'bird' (`id`, `name`, `latin`, `number`) values (0,'d','cwer','73')");
```

the first time, I could see the the values were added but when I reloaded, it didn't do any more, is it supposed to be like this ?
So if I want it to run every time I reload, how can I do that?

Comment: If your ID column is auto_increment, you can omit that value and your table will have new rows every time. `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'bird' (\`name\`, \`latin\`, \`number\`) values ('d','cwer','73')");`. You can also try removing any constricts such as UNIQUE/PRIMARY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a unique constraint against your `id` column (or another column in that query) and when you try to add a second row using the same ID it is rejected by MySQL.

You should be doing error checking in your code. You should be checking to see how many rows were affected by your insert (using [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)) and, if the number is zero, getting the error message from MySQL (using [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)).

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'bird' (`id`, `name`, `latin`, `number`) values (0,'d','cwer','73')");
if (mysqli_affected_rows() === 0) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

@DaveChen's comment above is a good solution to your (potential) problem. If it isn't already, make your `id` column [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and then leave it out of your query.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'bird' (`name`, `latin`, `number`) values ('d','cwer','73')");
```

Comment: Look at the second part of my answer to troubleshoot this

Comment: I used auto_increment and it worked but I still don't know why it didn't work with the way I used. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your id column is aut_increment and unique: change your code to:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","bird") ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bird");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'bird' (`id`, `name`, `latin`, `number`) values ('','d','cwer','73')");
```